# Keep track of read/unread User Messages with a MessageClicks table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, message

I'm trying to implement a **simple Inbox system** for users of my app so that can send basic messages to each other - just like in many forum systems.

**If `User has_many :messages`, how do I keep track of and notify the User of messages unread since last time they were read?**

I'm thinking clicks on the link to the `Messages` screen need to be recorded in a separate table (**`MessagesClicks`**).

*Is that the best approach here?*

So then I check the `MessagesClicks` table to see if any new messages have arrived since the last time that link was clicked - **based on a `last_clicked` or `updated_at` field**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would keep track of when a message was read on the message itself with the default value of null.

If the user has any Messages with a dateRead value of null then they have unread messages.

When you display a message to the user on the Messages screen, update the dateRead property of the message from null to now.

Comment: @user730569 in this case you could add a reference table that contains user_id and message_id (and maybe timestamps or other interesting information) and store that information there.

Comment: It won't work for conversations having multiple participants. For that you will have to make another association model, say, `ReadReceipt`