# How to tell if something has been read in Rails for notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to implement a simple notification system on my site where an unseen/unread item is displayed to the user. Similar to the one used across Stack Exchange for the user's inbox where unread comments on questions, etc are displayed.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561199/keep-track-of-read-unread-user-messages-with-a-messageclicks-table) that provides an overview of how I'd do this. What I'm confused about is how to figure out if something has been read. I could add a `read_at` column but how do I actually fill it? If anyone could help me with some basic guidance I'd appreciate it!

**UPDATE #1:** What if I add a conditional to my Item#show action where I check the `user_id` (ID of the user creating the item) against `current_user.id`. Something like the below:

```
unless @item.user_id == current_user.id
  @item.read_at = Time.now
end
```

**UPDATE #2:** Using the code below, I'm attempting to update the message's `read_at` if its `recipient_id` matches the `current_user` ID. However it's not working.

```
def show
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  if @message.recipient_id == current_user.id
    @message.read_at == Time.now
    @message.save
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @message }
  end
end
```

**FINAL UPDATE:** Thanks to @prasvin, here's my solution. I added a `read_at` column to the object. The object also has an existing `recipient_id` column. So in my Controller's show action, I put the following:

```
def show
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  if @message.recipient_id == current_user.id
    @message.update_attributes(:read_at => Time.now)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @message }
  end
end
```

Then in my helper.rb file:

```
def new_messages
  Message.where(:recipient_id => current_user.id, :read_at => nil).count
end
```

And in my layout:

```
<% if new_messages > 0 %><span class="notification"><%= new_messages %></span><% end %>
```

Comment: As a side note, I guess you can avoid explicitly stating the id. I mean, doing `@message.update_attributes(:read_at => Time.now) if @message.recipient_id == current_user`. Or, simply `@message.recipient` if you have in Message model `belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"` . Just do a check - if it works, it looks and reads nicer.

Comment: thank you. i was very stuck with something similar to this. much props for showing your progress and working code = ) i was trying to do this using a flash notification and your new_messages helper helped a lot = )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about filling in `read_at` column in show action, i.e. we have the object in the show action,and then update its read_at attribute before redering the page

Comment: But the first time the object is shown is after it was created right? So if I create a message, it shows, and the `read_at` would be filled by me. Right? Or no?

Comment: hmm, yea that requires more thought :). How about updating the read_at to nil for those objects that require notifications. So the read_at that was filled right after being created would not pose a problem. Meanwhile, lemme think of a better solution

Comment: I think its better to compare the read_at column to updated_at column. If you intend to show the object right after creation, the read_at is filled. If the object is updated, a notification is sent based on read_at and updated_at column. Hope this helps.

Comment: I just updated my question. If you have a moment I'd be curious to know what you think.

Comment: yea, that would prevent the user who created the item from populating the read_at column.  A single user when reads the item would fill the read_at column. But, what about other users who have not read the item ?
Can you present more information about the entire scenario. I know its creating an item and producing some sort of notification, but, I would like to know where exactly you are trying to fit this process in, that is if you'd like to share some information without any trouble :)

Comment: Well the messages have a `user_id` and `recipient_id` as well as `read_at`. So I figure I can target just the recipients and when they click the message the `read_at` gets registered, adjusting the number for notification purposes.

Comment: `recipient_id` will get rid of the 'multiple users who have not read the item' problem. Think you are getting there then :)

Comment: Now I just need to update the `read_at` attribute. I've tried with the code I put in my latest update but that's not working.

Comment: you did not save the item. what about doing `@item.update_attributes!(:read_at => Time.now)`